# Is there a way to exclude 'sudo' in history expansion?

Tags: linux, zsh, sudo

I'd like to be able to repeat commands that require sudo, but I'd like history expansion to ignore sudo when expanding the command.

for example:

say I run `sudo apt upgrade`, and then later when I run`!sud<tab>`
It will expand to `sudo apt upgrade`, but I'd like to be able to run `!apt<tab>`, and have it expand to `sudo apt upgrade`

Is this possible?

P.S. my shell preference is zsh